# BaseInputConnection's commitText method doesn't get called when number clicked

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I'm trying to implement custom soft keyboard behaviour and met an issue. I overrode onCreateInputConnection() and extended BaseInputConnection class. Now I expect method commitText() gets called when a key is clicked... and it does unless the number key is clicked. The number key goes directly to sendKeyEvent() method. Is there a way to handle numeric keys like any other keys? Thanks.

Here is the onCreateInputConnection method implementation. Nothing special.

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE;
    return new BaseInputConnection(this, true) {
        @Override
        public Editable getEditable() {
            return editable;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
            return super.commitText(text, newCursorPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: See also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969327/input-connection-for-numeric-type-keyboard